# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') in react dev

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

## in this the code is working normally when the api call is not done but when i make the call then it first render the normal code but after the api call it's not re-render the fetched data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3Nck.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMsMm.png)

please describe me the problem and how can i solve this as i am beginner in the react.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a null check whenever you are calling map function.

```
filteredRestaurant?.map(x => <RestaurantCard  />)
```